# Footer inner div's alignment

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am having difficulties getting my footer nav to display inline with my footer title. Here is a fiddle showing what I have done... https://jsfiddle.net/nkzsufov/

I have tried making this absolute/relative

```
.footerNav {
 margin-top: 35px;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 font-family: Oswald;
 float: left;
 position: absolute;
}
```

I have added `float: left;` to both the `footerNav` and `footerNav li`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your footerTitle needs to be floated left and drop the position:absolute from footerNav

Comment: Didn't help. Thanks though.

Comment: should have, https://jsfiddle.net/zn4eL92L/

Comment: You are correct it did help. I had a typo in the float. What is the best way to group this all together so it is responsive?

Comment: Give footerNav and footerTitle percentage widths and then change the font sizes in your media queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#footer_menu ul {
/* margin: 0px 30px; */
padding: 10px 30px;
list-style-type: none;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline;
}

#footer_menu ul li {
margin: 0 0;
padding: 5px 0;
display: inline-block;
color: white;
clear: both;
}
```

hope this will solve it

Comment: No it didn't help. I changed the id's to classes and the names.

Answer (score 0):

I modified two css classes from your JSFiddle and I guess I achieved what you wanted. I only added float:left and removed position attribute.

```
.footerTitle {
    font-size: 2.2em;
    font-family: Oswald;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 33px;
    float:left;
}

.footerNav {
    margin-top: 35px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-family: Oswald;
    float: left;
}
```